# I want total score and comment (based on total score) both in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the below code I tried to calculate the total score and based on that if the total score is less than 10, it will show some comment, else other comment. So basically I need the total score and comment both.

While trying, if I use calculateTotal function and delete getComment function, it works and vice versa. But when I am putting both functions, nothing comes. Here is my code.

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total Score by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var Scoring = getScore() + getScore1() + getScore2() + getScore3() + getScore4();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalScore');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Score for the selected answer "+Scoring;
    getComment(Scoring);
}

getComment(Scoring)
if (totalScore == 10) {
    document.getElementById("displaycomment").innerHTML = "Excellent Result"+Scoring;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("displaycomment").innerHTML = "See the guidebook"+Scoring;
}
```

Comment: No, that is not your code, that is an image of your code. Have you opened the console to see if you're getting an error message? Also, in your image, the getComment() function is NOT surrounded by { ... } -- put in your curlies!

Comment: Wow. now that is an even WORSE image of your code. Still, though, getComment is not in fact a function. So yeah.

Comment: Try editing your question and place your code sample in a code block: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code . That will make it easier for others to address your question.

Comment: In `getComment()` you compare "totalScore" which doesn't exist - it should be "Scoring". Also you compare for "equals 10" which is only correct if 10 is the maximum possible score.

Answer (score 0):

try same objet methods.

snippet not working you copy to html and run example.

```
var a = 2;

function getScore() {
    return a;
}

function getScore1() {
    return a;
}

function getScore2() {
    return a;
}

function getScore3() {
    return a;
}

function getScore4() {
    return a;
}

var calcClass = new function() {
    this.Scoring = function() {
        return getScore() + getScore1() + getScore2() + getScore3() + getScore4();
    }

    this.divobj = document.getElementById('totalScore');
    this.divobj.style.display = 'block';
    this.divobj.innerHTML = "Total Score for the selected answer " + this.Scoring();

    this.getComment = function() {
        if (this.Scoring() == 10) {
            document.getElementById("displaycomment").innerHTML = "Excellent Result " + this.Scoring();
        } else {
            document.getElementById("displaycomment").innerHTML = "See the guidebook " + this.Scoring();
        }
    }
}
alert("total " + calcClass.Scoring());
calcClass.getComment();

//try to console see and check result
//a = 3;
//calcClass.getComment();
//alert("total " + calcClass.Scoring());




<div class="scoregroup">total score <div id="totalScore"></div></div>
<div class="scoregroup">display comment <div id="displaycomment"></div>      </div>
```

Comment: Heyy There are no Stack overflow gurus ? **why not working this example  code snippet ?** but why run normal page...